# Dúvidas no uso do dataExporter

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Galera estou usando o dataExporter do primeFaces para exportar em pdf o conteúdo de uma dataTable. O problema é que o pdf não trás o nome das colunas, apenas do conteúdo. Nos exemplos que vi nos showcase, ele captura o nome das colunas e o título da tabela se houver.

Eis ai como estou usando a tag:

```
<p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="idDatabela" fileName="relatorio" pageOnly="true"   />
```

Comment: Vc poderia disponibilizar como estão as options da dataTable `idDatabela`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu vou deixar uma tabela que criei aqui e funcionou, criando as colunas, cada uma com seu nome. A unica coisa divergente é que eu criei um arquivo xls, do excel.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.lista}" var="variavel"
    id="dataTable"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Registro(s): {startRecord} a {endRecord} total de {totalRecords} - Página: {currentPage}/{totalPages}"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    emptyMessage="Não existem cadastros." paginator="true" rows="10">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">NOME DA COLUNA</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{variavel.nome}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage library="img" name="excel.png" width="24" />
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTable" fileName="listaXLS"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Eu tava dando mancada mesmo @Gustavo, eu colocava o nome da coluna no componente p:column, quando o componente que é capturado pelo p:dataExporter  é o f:facet como esta no seu exemplo. 
Obrigado pelo ajuda!